# Flash get only one value from html forms

Tags: python, html, flask

I have following `html` code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sell Weapons</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="{{ url_for('predict')}}"method="post">
    <label for="comment1">evaluate first product</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="comment1" name="comment" required="required"><br>
      <label for="comment2">evaluate second product</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="comment2" name="comment" required="required"><br>
      <label for="comment">evaluate third product</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="comment" name="comment" required="required"><br>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

 <h4 style="color:Violet;">
   {{ prediction_text }} </h4>

</body>
</html>
```

when we run it, I get following output :
[image]

in this form I wrote three text, but it is showing me only one, here is corresponding python code with `Flask`

```py
import numpy as np
from flask import Flask,request,jsonify,render_template
import pickle
from transformers import pipeline

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("Commenting.html")

@app.route('/predict',methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    text =  [x for x in request.form.values()]
    # text=list(text)
    return render_template('Commenting.html', prediction_text=text)
    # sentiment_pipeline = pipeline("sentiment-analysis")
    # result =sentiment_pipeline(text)[0]
    # if result['label']=='POSITIVE':
    #     return render_template('Commenting.html',prediction_text=f'emotion of comment is positive')
    # else:
    #     return render_template('Commenting.html', prediction_text=f'emotion of comment is not positive')

if __name__ =="__main__":
    app.run()
```

Could you please tell me why I can access only first text? Where are rest of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, when you submit the form, the browser collects the data and sends it to the server. However, since all three inputs have the same name attribute (`name="comment"`), the data from these inputs overwrite each other, and only the last one is retained.

You need to give each input field a unique name.

Something like this:

```
<input type="text" id="comment1" name="comment1" required="required"><br>
<input type="text" id="comment2" name="comment2" required="required"><br>
<input type="text" id="comment3" name="comment3" required="required"><br>
```

Comment: that is exactly   what i have tried, thanks, i  haver very interesting question and i hope that  stackoverflo  will help me